# Using RxJava to bind ViewHolder to RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, rx-java, android-recyclerview

I use RxJava to push the data to the ViewHolder and inside of the ViewHolder I use RxJava to fill the TextViews.

But sometimes the TextViews are still empty. I think it is a timing issue but I don't have a idea how to solve it :-(

This are the important methods from my adapter:

```java
@Override
public DataEntityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_event, parent, false);

    return new DataEntityViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataEntityViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final FacebookEvents.DataEntity item = mList.get(position);
    holder.cellDataSubject.onNext(item);
}
```

And this is my ViewHolder

```java
public class DataEntityViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.textView_cell_event_name)  TextView mTextViewName;
    @Bind(R.id.textView_cell_event_start) TextView mTextViewStart;
    @Bind(R.id.textView_cell_event_end)   TextView mTextViewEnd;

    @NonNull public final PublishSubject<FacebookEvents.DataEntity> cellDataSubject;

    public DataEntityViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        cellDataSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        bind();
    }

    private void bind() {

        cellDataSubject
                .subscribe(item -> {
                    mTextViewName.setText(item.getName());
                    mTextViewStart.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTime(item.getStart_time()));
                    mTextViewEnd.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTime(item.getEnd_time()));
                });
    }
}
```

Do I miss something?

Should I use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of the `PublishSubject`? But when I use a `BehaviorSubject` how is the best way to reset it that if the view is reused I don't see the old content?

Do I have to add `.subscribeOn()`?

Or is RxJava not the best way to push the data from the adapter to the ViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are already using Butterknife. Maybe you could find useful [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) by JakeWharton as well.
His [RxTextView](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding/widget/RxTextView.java) could be what you are looking for.

Comment: I will give them a try :-)